# How to handle delays of scheduled jobs and thus duplications by mistake? (caching? message brokers?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, architecture, duplicates, job-scheduling

In our project, we have scheduled jobs which send shipment requests for orders every 60 seconds. There must be exactly one request per order. Some jobs have delays (take around 70 seconds instead), which results in sending a request twice for the same order just because the previous job had a delay and a new one already started. How to ensure that only one request is sent per order no matter what delay there is?

My assumptions so far:

1. Add a flag to the database, lookup for it before processing a request for an order (we use DynamoDb)
2. Temporary store the result in caches (I'd assume even something like 10 minutes, cause delayed jobs usually don't take longer than 1,5 minutes, so it'd be a safe assumption)
3. Temporary store it in some message broker (similar to caching). We already use SQS and SNS in our project. Would it be appropriate to store messages about orders which were already processed there? Are message brokers ever used for scheduled jobs to ensure they don't duplicate each other?
4. Increase the interval between jobs to 2 mins. Even though delays are not longer than 1,5 mins in total now, it will not guarantee to prevent possible longer delays in the future. However, this solution would be simple enough

What do you think? What would be a good solution in this case, in terms of simple implementation, fast performance and preventing duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to make your operation **idempotent** by using *de-duplication logic* then you should ask the following questions to narrow down the possible options:

- In worst case how many times would you receive the exact same request?
- In worst case how much time would be between first and last duplicate requests?
- In worst case how much requests should be evaluated nearly at the same time during peak hours?
- Which storage system does allow me to use point query instead of scan?
- Which storage system does have the lowest overhead during write operation to capture the *I have seen this* flag?
- ...

Depending on your answers you can justify that the given storage is suitable for your needs or not.